# how to pass variable to javascript from console

Tags: node.js, cron

I can pass variable in console and set crontab like this in php how can I do in nodejs

`*/5 * * * * php /var/www/html/acairpor/airpo.php BKKe`

Comment: What is the problem with a crontab line like `*/5 * * * * node /path/to/script.js param1 param2`? And if it's about accessing the paramters in the script, read https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#processargv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*/5 * * * * node /path/to/script value1 value2 ...`

then `value1` will be stored in `process.argv[2]` and `value2` will be stored in `process.argv[3]`... etc

Comment: You probably wouldn't want to execute a PHP script with node ...